# Span on click move to a div

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make make it possible that when someon click on move to then the page moves slowy to up where there is container division how ever it doesnt work

Here's a snippet to see my code running

```js
     $("#myButton").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
        }, 2000);} );
```

```css
.container{    
    height:400px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" class="container">
</div>      
 <footer>
 <p class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
  <span id="myButton">Move to Up</span>
 </p> &copy; 2018 Sell It, Inc. 
 <a href="#">Terms </a> &middot; 
 <a href="#">Conditions</a>
</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2L2y56pz/2/

Extra question. Why the page goes up when I click terms or conditions?

Comment: It work now [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2L2y56pz/3/) | Answer to extra question: Because it has `#`, remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO make it easier to see it working, I applied a size to the body, scroll down then click on Move Up to see it working.
I Just changed the function call method to `on('click', ...)`.
Also I've added a `cursor:pointer` to the span, to be clearer that it's clickable.

About your extra question, I think it's because of the `#` that your are using in the href, that made the page reload.

```js
 $("#myButton").on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000);   
});
```

```css
.container{  
  height:400px;
  background-color:red;
}
#myButton{
 cursor: pointer;
}
body{
 height: 750px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" class="container">
</div> 
 
 <footer><p class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i><span id="myButton">Move to Up</span> </p> &copy; 2018 Sell It, Inc. <a href="#">Terms </a> &middot; <a href="#">Conditions</a></footer>
```

**EDIT for extra question**
If you don't want the page to reload on `#`, use the real url or you can wrap those buttons in a section and anchor to it, something like this:

```css
    .container{  
      height:400px;
      background-color:red;
    }
    #myButton{
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    body{
     height: 750px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" class="container">
</div> 

 <footer>
   <p class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
      <span id="myButton">Move to Up</span> 
   </p> &copy; 2018 Sell It, Inc. 
<section id='terms_conditions'>
    <a href="#terms_conditions">Terms </a> &middot; <a href="#terms_conditions">Conditions</a>
</section>
 </footer>
```

Comment: about extra question what should I use instead of #?

Comment: the real link to the original pages... or if it don't exist yet, just disable that links or see my edit